# How do I put a recessed light in a wet location, where the can itself will get wet?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, deck, recessed-lighting

I have an underdeck porch that has a ceiling made of metal roofing panels, that diverts deck drainage into a gutter. I would like to install recessed lighting in the ceiling. However, the cans will exposed to water from the deck drainage.

Is there a way to install a can light in such an environment?

Comment: I think you'd have to build and wire the whole thing as if there was no deck and you were just going to have it be outdoors. That means outdoor rated cable/conduit rated for wet locations. This is a serious project, that also means some seriously increased costs. It will mean sealed fixtures, and I doubt you'll find recessed. I've typically seen the common "jar style" fixtures for wet locations.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk Recessed was the key here. I could do pendant lights easily with a waterproof electrical box.

Answer (score 2):

The cans themselves are not wet rated.

You should install a fixture that is. Such as a strip light that is sealed and gasketed. Something rated for outdoors.

Good luck!

Comment: No one makes a wet rated can? I also was considering epoxy sealing the cans themselves, since IC rated ones shouldn't need to breathe.

Comment: Usually serviceability and accessibility is a factor  in electrical code. Enough epoxy to seal against water, would certainly make it less serviceable.